# How to clear a Dropdown programmatically in React Semantic UI

Tags: semantic-ui-react

I'm using Semantic UI in React, and I have two dropdown forms. The first dropdown has options *Yes* and *No*, and the second dropdown has the options *A* and *B*. **If the first form has the option "Yes" selected (or if it is cleared), then I want the second dropdown to be cleared and disabled.**

Currently, I have it such that the second dropdown is disabled as described, but I cannot figure out how to *also* clear the selected option (if there is one). I cannot do it in the same way that I disabled the dropdown (by saving a state variable), because Dropdown has the property clear**able**, not clear**ed**.

Alternatively, could I set the second dropdown to some other third option *C* that is **only** set when it is disabled (and not accessible as an option)?

I've put below a Minimum Reproducible Example that demonstrates the disabling, but obviously not the clearing.

Thanks!

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown, Form} from "semantic-ui-react"

const firstDropdownOptions= [
  {
    key: 'Yes',
    text: 'Yes',
    value: 'Yes',
  },
  {
    key: 'No',
    text: 'No',
    value: 'No',
  },
]
const secondDropdownOptions= [
  {
    key: 'A',
    text: 'A',
    value: 'A',
  },
  {
    key: 'B',
    text: 'B',
    value: 'B',
  },
]

export const InputForm = () => {
  const [firstVal, setFirstVal] = useState('')
  const [secondVal, setSecondVal] = useState('')

  const [condition, setCondition] = useState(false)

   return (
    <Form>
        <Dropdown
          placeholder='First Value'
          selection
          clearable
          options={firstDropdownOptions}
          onChange={(_, data) => {setFirstVal(data.value)};
            if(data.value=="No"){setCondition(true)}
            else{setCondition(false)};
            }
        />
        <Dropdown
          placeholder='Second Value'
          selection
          clearable
          disabled={condition}
          options={secondDropdownOptions}
          onChange={(_, data) => setSecondVal(data.value)}
        />
    </Form>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dropdown` should have `value` prop. But when clearing existing value in the second `Dropdown`, make sure to follow this instruction: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3625#issuecomment-654199235